# Distinguishing between a bounce and a complaint in Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services

I recently started to play around with Amazon SES. When I intentionally tried to send an email to a non-existing account the bounce back email comes from email-bounces.amazonses.com. Does anyone know how a complaint will look like? Does it come from email-complaints.amazonses.com?

I am trying to figure out a way to distinguish between complaints and hard bounces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like this:

> complaints @ email-abuse.amazonses.com

Yes, I have 8% complaints on a site that is using email verification for registration. So much hate for nothing I did :(